# xlsx write function, importing data from matlab to excel not working, losing data

Tags: matlab, import, xlsx

I am having trouble importing data into an xlsx file from matlab. When I write

```
sample = [1;2;3;4] <br/> <br/>
A = {'Title'; sample};

xlswrite(filename, A);
```

I get the the title showing up on excel but no column numbers below it.  When I erase the curly braces and the string 'Operating Point' (i.e. A = sample)  I do get a column of numbers 1,2,3,4.  However it won't let me put a title with the numbers below it.  Can anyone help me figure out what I am doing wrong.  I was going by an example I saw on the mathworks help page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you want to write both strings and numbers to Excel, you need to write a cell array. Importantly, each element of the cell array gets written to a single Excel cell. In your case, you'd be trying to write a vector into the second cell, which won't work.

Here's what you want to do:

```
sample = [1;2;3;4]

%# transform sample to a cell array
%# with one number per element
sample = num2cell(sample); 

%# create header
header = {'Title'};

A = [header;sample];

xlswrite(filename, A);
```

Comment: great thanks! would you know how to apply this for a csv file?  I tried using the same technique but as you can imagine it didn't work with that.

Comment: You cannot write mixed numeric and string data with `csvwrite`. If you want headers, you need to use commands such as `fprintf`.